# cannot find symbol when compile a FileUpload servlet with Part class jsp

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a File Upload Servlet. I want to receive a file from a form and save it to server. But during compilation with cmd I find the error **cannot find symbol**.

```
    index.jsp
    <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="file">
    </form>

    UploadServlet.java
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();//This line shows error cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Please describe (in short copy paste) exact error that occurs. :D It would be beneficial. Context of the symbol means a lot.

Comment: I am trying to compile a servlet manually with cmd and found the
error: cannot find symbol
String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getSubmittedFileName()
  location: variable filePart of type Part
1 error
Basically I need the name of the file that is uploaded/Submitted from index.jsp